# Memory Usage Planning - recommendations?

Tags: marklogic

What is the recommended ratio of forest size to real memory for a MarkLogic server?  For example, I currently have a 190GB database that is growing over time.  I eventually need to cluster this database as the database will continually grow.  As such, I need to develop a plan for how many nodes I'll need and with what disk and memory configurations.

Comment: Memory needs will depend a lot on the range indexes you have configured - wow many and what kind as well as the # of docs per node.  You'll want those to fitin memory.  I think there was a talk at recent MarkLogic World about this.  I'll hunt for a reference.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. You'll hear numbers like 1:10 or 1:16, but variations in content structure and index configuration can swing that number by 10x in either direction.

But since you already have a 190-GB database, this is relatively easy. Check each forest status page for the in-memory size, and add those up. Multiply by 8/3 (or about 2.7).

If you don't have an existing database, the most accurate technique is to load a significant percentage (say 5%) of your content with the correct index configuration. Then merge everything down to one stand, and check the forest-status page for the in-memory size. Multiple that by the proportion of total content. Conservatively, that number will be 3/8 of total physical memory needed. So if you see 1-GB for 5% of your content, then the total will be 20 * 8 / 3 = 53.33-GB and you will want a 64-GB server.